# Java - How to export and import some MySql tables using a Json file?

Tags: json, spring-boot, java-17

I have a requirement to let user be able to export some tables from MySql from one environment to a Json file to be imported on another environment. I was trying to execute a query on JpaRepository with all tables related, then converting to a json file and then converting this json file to an entity to be imported.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe [batch-processing](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) can help you.

Comment: User wants to select the tables and export and import online.